# Django Model design and user profile

Tags: django, django-models

I want to implement **Organisation,department and user relation model**. Where in super user of organisation can add departments along with department details like phone, address, email etc. A user can belongs to one are more departments, and user with department owner or organisation super user can edit user info as well department info.

After analysis,I came up with below model relation.

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Departments(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email= models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    phone=  models.CharField(max_length=30)
    org_linked=models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    user_linked=models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Please let me know how can I complete this model by adding other properties like

-Org super user

-Department super user

-Users Edit permission

-Adding/Deleting user as super user other permission

Answer (score 0):

just add a boolean field for each property you want to add to your instance to define its type, is superuser or anything else